# how to open a file after writing to it using Bash (in one line)

Tags: bash

is there a way to
open or cat a file that's been newly created e.g.

```
cat $(cat 1210.hc.vcf | head -n1 > ok.txt )
open $(cat 1210.hc.vcf | head -n1 > ok.txt )
```

Open a file after writing to it using Bash (in one line)

Comment: What do you mean by `open` a file ? Open a GUI text editor ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tee` to write to stdout and the file.

```
head -n 1 1210.hc.vcf | tee ok.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

What comes in my mind:

```
cat 1210.hc.vcf | head -n1 > ok.txt; cat !$
```